# MS Access SQL getting results from different tables and sorting by date

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

i hope my description will be enough. i tried to remove all non-significant fields.

i have 5 tables (Customer, Invoice, Items, Invoice_Item, Payment):

Customer fields and sample date are:

```
+----+------+
| ID | Name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
|  2 | Mary |
+----+------+
```

Invoice fields and sample date are:

```
+----+-----------+----------+------+
| ID |   Date    | Customer | Tax  |
+----+-----------+----------+------+
|  1 | 1.1.2017  |        1 | 0.10 |
|  2 | 2.1.2017  |        2 | 0.10 |
|  3 | 3.1.2017  |        1 | 0.10 |
|  4 | 3.1.2017  |        2 | 0.10 |
|  5 | 8.1.2017  |        1 | 0.10 |
|  6 | 11.1.2017 |        1 | 0.10 |
|  7 | 12.1.2017 |        2 | 0.10 |
|  8 | 13.1.2017 |        1 | 0.10 |
+----+-----------+----------+------+
```

Item fields and sample data are:

```
+----+--------+
| ID |  Name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Door   |
|  2 | Window |
|  3 | Table  |
|  4 | Chair  |
+----+--------+
```

Invoice_Item fields and sample data are:

```
+------------+---------+--------+------------+
| Invoice_ID | Item_ID | Amount | Unit_Price |
+------------+---------+--------+------------+
|          1 |       1 |      4 |         10 |
|          1 |       2 |      2 |         20 |
|          1 |       3 |      1 |         30 |
|          1 |       4 |      2 |         40 |
|          2 |       1 |      1 |         10 |
|          2 |       3 |      1 |         15 |
|          2 |       4 |      2 |         12 |
|          3 |       3 |      4 |         15 |
|          4 |       1 |      1 |         10 |
|          4 |       2 |     20 |         30 |
|          4 |       3 |     15 |         30 |
|          5 |       1 |      4 |         10 |
|          5 |       2 |      2 |         20 |
|          5 |       3 |      1 |         30 |
|          5 |       4 |      2 |         40 |
|          6 |       1 |      1 |         10 |
|          6 |       3 |      1 |         15 |
|          6 |       4 |      2 |         12 |
|          7 |       3 |      4 |         15 |
|          8 |       1 |      1 |         10 |
|          8 |       2 |     20 |         30 |
|          8 |       3 |     15 |         30 |
+------------+---------+--------+------------+
```

The reason the price is in this table not in the item table is because it is customer specific price.

Payment fields are:

```
+----------+--------+-----------+
| Customer | Amount |   Date    |
+----------+--------+-----------+
|        1 |     40 | 3.1.2017  |
|        2 |     10 | 7.1.2017  |
|        1 |     60 | 10.1.2017 |
+----------+--------+-----------+
```

so my report should be combine all tables and sort by DATE (either from Invoice or Payment) for a certain customer.

so for e.g. for customer John (1) it should be like:

```
+------------+----------------+---------+-----------+
| Invoice_ID | Invoice_Amount | Payment |   Date    |
+------------+----------------+---------+-----------+
| 1          | 171            | -       | 1.1.2017  |
| 3          | 54             | -       | 3.1.2017  |
| -          | -              | 40      | 3.1.2017  |
| 5          | 171            | -       | 8.1.2017  |
| -          | 10             | 60      | 10.1.2017 |
| 6          | 44.1           | -       | 11.1.2017 |
| 8          | 954            | -       | 13.1.2017 |
+------------+----------------+---------+-----------+
```

it is sorted by date, Invoice amount is (sum of (Amount* unit price)) * (1-tax)

i started with union but then got lost.

here is my try:

```
SELECT Inv_ID as Num, SUM(Invoice_Items.II_Price*Invoice_Items.II_Amount) AS Amount, Inv_Date as Created
FROM Invoice INNER JOIN Invoice_Items ON Invoice.Inv_ID = Invoice_Items.II_Inv_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT Null as Num, P_Value as Amount, P_Date as Created
FROM Payments
ORDER BY created ASC
```

Your help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the report you requested using the following SQL script:

```
SELECT CustomerID,Invoice_ID,Invoice_Amount,Payment,Date

FROM (

SELECT c.ID AS CustomerID, i.ID AS Invoice_ID, SUM((t.Amount * t.UnitPrice)*(1-i.tax)) AS Invoice_Amount, NULL AS Payment,i.Date
FROM (Customer c
LEFT JOIN Invoice i
ON c.ID = i.Customer)
LEFT JOIN Invoice_Item t
ON i.ID = t.Invoice_ID
GROUP BY c.ID, i.ID,i.Date

UNION

SELECT c.ID AS CustomerID,NULL AS Invoice_ID, NULL AS Invoice_Amount, p.Amount AS Payment, p.Date
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Payment p
ON c.ID = p.Customer ) a

ORDER BY CustomerID, Date, Payment ASC
```

Note: I've added CustomerID to the output so you know what customer the data corresponds to.

Comment: thank you, i think there are 2 small mistakes, the tax is i.tax not t, and on the second left joing it should be i.iD = t.Invoice_ID, even when i correct them, i get the error :" syntax error (Missing operator) in query expression 'c.ID = i.Customer
LEFT JOIN Invoice_Item t
ON i.ID = t.Invoice_ID'"

Comment: Opps, i've made the changes. Could you paste the full error message here?. Also please double check the spelling of the column names.

Comment: Added a parenthesis to the first query as access don't like multiple joins. Check now.

Comment: it seems access does not like many things :), the error above was solved, but access prompts me to enter the date field

Comment: @Augustus please check the column names of the corresponding tables. Access prompts to enter the date because it's misspelled or doesn't exist.

Comment: the AS was missing in both Statements for the Date, as well i changed Date because it is a reserved keyword, now it throws some output, but does not seems to be correct, i need to double check it and come back to you. thanks

Comment: @Augustus sure. I guess you can wrap the date in square brackets to avoid the reserved word scenario. Sorry I don't have a sample data set or access to test the script. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the first part before the union is working, the second part is not showing the payments, it shows them as empty. but you were a great help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is the Answer which worked for me, a bit corrected from @Catzeye Answer , which didnt show the second part of the Union.

```
SELECT c.ID AS CustomerID,NULL AS Invoice_ID, NULL AS Invoice_Amount, p.Amount AS Payment, p.Date
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Payment p
ON c.ID = p.Customer

UNION ALL

SELECT c.ID AS CustomerID, i.ID AS Invoice_ID, SUM((t.Amount * t.Unit_Price)*(1-i.tax)) AS Invoice_Amount, NULL AS Payment,i.Date
FROM (Customer c
INNER JOIN Invoice i
ON c.ID = i.Customer)
INNER JOIN Invoice_Item t
ON i.ID = t.Invoice_ID
GROUP BY c.ID, i.ID,i.Date

ORDER BY CustomerID, Date, Payment;
```